# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm getting this render error:
[image]

and asked to check the render method of 'HospitalInfo' (provided below). I am using react native. I am getting this error in my android simulator. I can provide the JSON of the data structure from which i am trying to extract if that will help too.

```
import { View, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Colors from '../../../assets/Shared/Colors'
import  { Ionicons }  from '@expo/vector-icons';
import ActionButton from './ActionButton';
import PageHeader from '../Shared/PageHeader';
import SubHeading from '../Home/SubHeading';
import HorizontalLine from '../Shared/HorizontalLine';

export default function HospitalInfo( {hospital} ) {
    return hospital && (
        <View>
            <Text style={{
                fontSize: 23,
                fontFamily: 'appfont-semi'
            }}>{hospital.attributes.Name}</Text>

            <FlatList
                data={hospital.attributes?.category?.data}
                horizontal={true}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <Text style={{
                        marginRight: 10, color: Colors.GRAY
                    }}>{item.attributes.Name},</Text>
                )}
            />

           <HorizontalLine/>
            <View style={{
                display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row',
                gap: 5, alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
                <Ionicons name="location" size={22} color={Colors.PRIMARY} />
                <Text style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'appfont',
                    color: Colors.GRAY
                }}>{hospital.attributes.Address}</Text>
            </View>

            <View style={{
                display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row',
                gap: 5, alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop:6
            }}>
                <Ionicons name="time" size={22} color={Colors.PRIMARY} />
                <Text style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: 'appfont',
                    color: Colors.GRAY
                }}>Mon Sun | 11AM - 8 PM</Text>
            </View>

         

            <ActionButton/>

            <View style={{
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                marginTop:15,
                borderColor: Colors.LIGHT_GRAY, margin: 5, marginBottom: 15
            }}></View>

            <SubHeading subHeadingTitle={'About'}/>
            <Text>{hospital.attributes?.Description}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Remember to put the error in your post, too.

Answer (score 0):

That error typically comes from one of two issues:

1. you are trying to output a value that is an Object where you think the value is a string.  For example, if `hospital.attributes.Address` is an object like `{line1: "123 main street", city: "Toronto"}` and not a string.
2. you have imported a component incorrectly such `import ActionButton from './ActionButton'` but the export from `'./ActionButton'` isn't a Component but some other object.  [Frequently this can be solved by doing `import { ActionButton } from './ActionButton'` if ActionButton is a named export].

Comment: Hi, the value associated with "Address" is a simple text string containing the address information. I double checked and all components are being imported correctly.

Comment: So I would start commenting out parts of your above JSX return value until the problem goes away.  Then bring the parts back in until you find out exactly which line of the JSX is giving that error.  Then  you'll know if it is a variable or a component that is throwing that error.